# $f(x) = (2x-1)/x^2$: proof of continuity using the epsilon-delta definition

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, epsilon-delta

$f(x)=(2x−1)/x^2$ , where $x$ is in real number, except $0$.

I have been struggling with this for a while what seems to be quite trivial. I have started with
$$|f(x)−f(c)|=\left|\frac{2x−1}{x^2}−\frac{2c−1}{c^2}\right|$$
and tried to cancel and approximate the terms as much as possible using triangle inequality and the properties of polynomial fractions and somehow squeeze in delta so that i can define it in terms of epsilon. If someone could leave some hints, i would appreciate it thanks.

Comment: You will need to come up with the term $|x-c|$ on the RHS. Did you do that?

Comment: that is exactly what i was going for, but that's where i am stuck at.

Comment: When you don't see the pattern, at least you can try writing all $x$ (at the top) to $(x-c)+c$ and hope for the best. You may try this first...

Comment: how would you go about this? could you give more specific steps?

Comment: Can you show some work and point out where you are stuck? I would then give you some specific hints.

Comment: I tried multiplying each terms by x^2/x^2 and c^2/c^2 as to bring the two terms together by having the same denominator. But after that is where i am stuck. There are no terms that cancel out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x,c\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$, then\begin{align}f(x)-f(c)&=\frac{2 x c^2-c^2-2 x^2 c+x^2}{c^2 x^2}\\&=\frac{c+x-2cx}{c^2x^2}(x-c).\end{align}Now, suppose that $|x-c|<\frac{|c|}2$. It follows from this that $|x|>\frac{|c|}2$ and that $|x|<\frac{3|c|}2$. Therefore\begin{align}\bigl|f(x)-f(c)\bigr|&<\frac{|c|+\frac32|c|+3c^2}{c^4/4}|x-c|\\&=\frac{10|c|+12c^2}{c^4}|x-c|.\end{align}So, if$$\delta=\min\left\{\frac{|c|}2,\frac{c^4\varepsilon}{10|c|+12c^2}\right\},$$you will have $|x-c|<\delta\implies\bigl|f(x)-f(c)\bigr|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: This helps a lot! Thanks. But the one part that is not clear to me is, how did you come up with $|x -c| <|c|/2 $?

Comment: Since in$$\frac{c+x-2cx}{c^2x^2}$$there are two $x$'s in the numerator, I had to begin with a restriction of the type $|x-c|<a$ that doesn't allow them to be too big. Actually, *any* $a>0$ would do, since $|x-c|<a\implies|x|<a+|c|$. But that $x$ in the denominator should be kept away from $0$, so that the fraction doesn't get too large. So, I took $|x-c|<\frac{|c|}2$, since this implies that $|x|>\frac{|c|}2$. Instead of $\frac{|c|}2$, I could have taken any number $a\in\bigl(0,|c|\bigr)$.